# $C(X,Y)$ complete

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that:

> $C(X,Y)$ is complete in the compact-open topology, when every component of $X$ is locally compact with a countable base, and $Y$ is a complete metric space.

The proof I am following is in the book "Differential topology" by Hirsch.

We do this by showing that $C(X_n, Y)$ is complete, where $\{X_n\}$ is a countable covering of $X$, by compact sets.

My question is:

How do we get this countable covering? Can we assume that $X$ is locally compact with a countable base, because every component is?

Comment: It seems that something here is wrong. Let $X$ be an uncountable  discrete space. Then each component of $X$ is a point, that is a locally compact space with a countable base, but $X$ is not $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: I am confused by this same point in Hirsch's book.

Comment: In the comment of this page there is a explanation. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994909/complete-metric-for-the-compact-open-topology