# Complete metric for the compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

The following is claimed in *Differential Topology* by Hirsch (Theorem 2.4.1, p. 59), with $X,Y$ topological spaces and $C_W(X,Y)$ the [compact-open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) or "weak" topology on the set of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$:

> **Theorem**. Let each component of $X$ be locally compact with a countable base; let $Y$ be a complete metric space. Then $C_W(X,Y)$ has a complete metric.

The proof begins as follows:

> **Proof**. It suffices to construct a complete metric on $C_W(X_\alpha,Y)$ for each component $X_\alpha$ of $X$; therefore we assume $X$ locally compact with a countable base.

**My question**: why is this true if $X$ has uncountably many components?

If $X$ had countably many components $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ with complete metrics $d_1,d_2,\ldots$ on $C_W(X_1,Y),C_W(X_2,Y),\ldots$ then I believe I can define a complete metric on $C_W(X,Y)$ by the formula $$d(f,g):= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{d_i\left(f|_{X_i},g|_{X_i}\right)}{1+d_i\left(f|_{X_i},g|_{X_i}\right)},$$

but I can't figure out what to do if $X$ does not have countably many components.

Comment: "why is this true if X has uncountably many components?" It isn't. If $X$ is a discrete space, then $C_W(X,Y) \cong Y^X$, and the product $Y^X$ is metrisable if and only if a) $Y$ contains at most one point, or b) $X$ is countable (finite or countably infinite). And if the components aren't open, there are problems too. In differential topology, one works with manifolds, where the definition often includes second countability. I guess it's a mis-generalisation from the manifold case.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the answer. I wasted quite a bit of time on this.